# How do I make sure that opening a folder via Win + R > {path to folder} always opens the file explorer in fullscreen mode?

Tags: windows-explorer, fullscreen, windows-10-v1607

Is it possible to pass extra options when opening file explorer via Win+R?

I know `chrome.exe -incognito {URL}` opens the URL in incognito. So I tried, `{path} -fullscreen` and `{path} --fullscreen`, but no avail.

Comment: It's not quite clear if you want to maximize Explorer or Chrome.

Comment: I want to maximize Explorer. Sorry if my post was not clear.

Comment: Then I believe there's no simple way to do this. At least without an additional software like AutoIt.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will look up AutoIt.

Comment: Instead of typing `-fullscreen` before it opens, it would be much simpler to type F11 afterward.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this will fit my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command-line switch for explorer.exe that will get you to a full-screen window. But you can get close to your desired behavior with this approach.

Create this VBScript:

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Explorer = objShell.Exec("%WINDIR%\explorer.exe " & WScript.Arguments(0))
Wscript.Sleep 500
objShell.AppActivate Explorer.ProcessID
objShell.SendKeys "{F11}"
```

Save it somewhere in your path. Give it a short name, like "e.vbs". Then, at a Start -> Run (aka <kbd>Win+R</kbd>) prompt, you can type `e.vbs C:\Temp` and you'll get a full-screen Explorer window at C:\Temp.

(If you are doing this from a command prompt, you can skip the extension, and just use `e C:\Temp`. This is because the PathExt environment variable will know to look for a file with a `vbs` extension, but I can't get the Start -> Run interface to honor PathExt.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for my usecase, I will probably go with the suggestion provided by @harrymc above.